# The multi-part identifier "t7.rate_buy" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please help me on this error message:

> The multi-part identifier "t7.rate_buy" could not be bound.

I can't find how to fix this. I use SQL Server 2012 and I have tried everything but I can't figure out what the solution is.

Thank you

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.q_no
     , (
         SELECT rate_buy
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[rates_exchange]
         WHERE date_r=t1.q_date
     ) AS t7
     , t1.account_name
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.maden/ t7.rate_buy) AS ex32
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t5
         WHERE t1.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS m_f
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.daen/(t7.rate_buy)) AS ex33
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t6
         WHERE t1.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS d_f
     , t1.third_id, t1.maden,t1.daen, t1.bayen, t1.q_date, t1.cur
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.maden/t7.rate_buy - t1.daen/t7.rate_buy) AS Expr5
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t2
         WHERE (id <= t1.id) AND t1.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS tot
     , t1.snd_type, t1.r_no
 FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] t1
 WHERE t1.third_id = 'F1' AND t1.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021'
 GROUP BY t1.id, t1.q_no, t1.account_name, t1.q_date, t1.third_id, t1.snd_type, t1.r_no, t1.daen, t1.maden, t1.bayen, t1.cur
```

Comment: It would certainly help if you laid out your query in a clear manner and were consistent with your coding practices, upper/lower case etc.

Comment: Check out `cross apply` and `outer apply`. If you use that  (in the `from` clause) then you'll be able to reference `t7.rate_buy` that way. You also need to make sure it's a scalar result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference another calculated column at the same level of the query as its defined (except for ordering). One solution is to calculate `rate_buy` as a sub-query e.g.

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.q_no
     , t1.account_name
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.maden/t1.rate_buy) AS ex32
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t5
         WHERE t1.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS m_f
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.daen/(t1.rate_buy)) AS ex33
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t6
         WHERE t1.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS d_f
     , t1.third_id, t1.maden, t1.daen, t1.bayen, t1.q_date, t1.cur
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t1.maden/t1.rate_buy - t1.daen/t1.rate_buy) AS Expr5
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t2
         WHERE (id <= t1.id) AND t1.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t1.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS tot
     , t1.snd_type, t1.r_no
 FROM (
     SELECT *
         , (
             SELECT rate_buy
             FROM [dta].[dbo].[rates_exchange]
             WHERE date_r = t1.q_date
         ) AS rate_buy
     FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed]
 ) AS t1
 WHERE t1.third_id = 'F1' AND t1.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021'
 GROUP BY t1.id, t1.q_no, t1.account_name, t1.q_date, t1.third_id, t1.snd_type, t1.r_no, t1.daen, t1.maden, t1.bayen, t1.cur;
```

Given you reference `t1` in your 3 sub-queries, that removes the point of having them. I suspect you actually want the following, where `t5`, `t6` & `t2` are actually used.

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.q_no
     , t1.account_name
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t5.maden/t1.rate_buy)
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t5
         WHERE t5.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t5.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS m_f
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t6.daen/(t1.rate_buy))
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t6
         WHERE t6.q_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t6.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS d_f
     , t1.third_id, t1.maden, t1.daen, t1.bayen, t1.q_date, t1.cur
     , (
         SELECT SUM(t2.maden/t1.rate_buy - t2.daen/t1.rate_buy)
         FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed] AS t2
         WHERE (t2.id <= t1.id)
         AND t2.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021' AND t2.third_id = 'F1'
     ) AS tot
     , t1.snd_type, t1.r_no
 FROM (
     SELECT *
         , (
             SELECT rate_buy
             FROM [dta].[dbo].[rates_exchange]
             WHERE date_r = t1.q_date
         ) AS rate_buy
     FROM [dta].[dbo].[qyed]
 ) AS t1
 WHERE t1.third_id = 'F1' AND t1.[q_date] BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '01/01/2021'
 GROUP BY t1.id, t1.q_no, t1.account_name, t1.q_date, t1.third_id, t1.snd_type, t1.r_no, t1.daen, t1.maden, t1.bayen, t1.cur;
```

However if that is what you want then you can probably use window function `sum` rather than a sub-query. I would have a go, but without sample data I can't work out how that would interact with your massive `group by`.

Comment: I think your original query is wrong, you have a bunch of sub-queries which calculate `m_f`, `d_f` and `tot`, which all use the `qyed` table, but all reference `t1` instead of the local table e.g. `t5`,`t6`,`t2`....

Comment: i try your answer sir @Dale K
  other error message show   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. after i try your edit sql –

Comment: Clearly your original query didn't work - but I have solved the error you were asking about.

Comment: i try your answer and get this error                     Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. after i try your edit sql –

Comment: My guess is the sub-query to obtain the `rate_buy` has multiple rows that match the date `WHERE date_r = t1.q_date` in which case you need a way to identify which row it rate it should use.